# Use modifier function to create heirachy of smart contracts

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, web3js, nodejs, modifiers

I have 3 contracts that I want to implement. The contracts are `master` , `admin` and `customer`. So the master contract is initiated by a single person, the owner of the private chain (based on geth). The `admin` contract provides access to certain addresses. These `admin` instances are created by the `master`. I am using a `modifier` to ensure this. The `customer` contract can be interacted with only by the `admin` and `master` contract.

I have mapped these `addresses` to accounts (with username and pw) stored on my local `Redis db`. Snipper of my contract structure is below:

`Master Contract`

```
contract MasterContract{
    bool public state = false;
    address public masterAddress;
    bool permCheck;


    // ACL
    // Subject(Role) - Object/Subject - permission - On/Off
    mapping (uint => mapping(uint => perm)) public acl;

    // Init Function
    function masterContractInit(string name,string detail){
      if(msg.sender!="0x0"){
        throw;
      }else{
        masterAddress = msg.sender;
      }
    }

    modifier onlyMasterAccess{
      if (msg.sender == masterAddress) _
      else throw;
    }
}
```

The admin contract

```
contract AdminContract{
  bool state=false;
  struct Admin{
      bool status;
      string name;
  }
  mapping (address => admin ) public admins;

  // How to reference this masterAddress?
  modifier checkMasterAndAdminAccess{
    if (msg.sender == masterAddress || admins[msg.sender].status) _
    else throw;
  }

  function initAdminContract() onlyMasterAccess{    
    state = true;
  }

  function addAdmin(address addr, string name) onlyMasterAccess{
    admins[addr]=Admin(true, name);
  }

  function revokeAdmin(address addr) onlyMasterAccess{
    if(addr!="0x0"){
      throw;
    }else{
      admins[addr].status = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Customer contract

```
contract Customer{
  bool public state = false;

  function initCustomerContract() onlyMasterAccess{    
    state = true;
  }

  function foo() checkMasterAndAdminAccess{
    // Do something here
    // only admin or master can call this function
  }

  function bar(){
    // Do something, but allow others to modify this
  }   
}
```

Now I need to further understand how to combine these contracts and reference the master and admin address in customer contract to use the modifier `checkMasterAndAdminAccess`. Ideally when compiling into ABI and using it in my `Nodejs` app, I would want to place these contracts into separate files as they will become massive.

Is this a recommended practice?

There will only be one instance of `master contract` controlled by only person (so only one address will have access to it). The other contracts may be instantiated more than once

Can I get some guidance on how to achieve the above.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to allow other contracts to access your code you should use inheritance:

`Customer is Admin:`

Though this doesn't make much sense to me.  I think your issue is less about sharing functionality and more about the way you're organizing your code.  The easiest way to deal with permissions is to have a phone book contract that keeps track of user permissions.  Then have all your functions inherit from that contract so they can use the necessary modifiers.  Like this:

```
contract PhoneBook {
    modifier onlyMasterAccess() {
        require(msg.sender == master);
        _;
    }
}


contract Customer is PhoneBook{
    function initCustomerContract() onlyMasterAccess {    
        state = true;
  }
}
```